# Создание собственного экрана блокировки

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.

Меня интересует создание собственного экрана блокировки. 
Функциональность следующая: После нажатия кнопки блокировки на устройстве, отображается мой экран блокировки вместо стандартного, на нем одна кнопка, после нажатия кнопки снимается блокировка (отображается рабочий стол). Как это реализовать?

Провел несколько часов в поисках, но ничего не нашел. Вообще, интересно, как создают shell (например, [Yandex.Shell](URL), [SPB Shell](URL), [3D, TSF Shell](URL))

Буду рад абсолютно любой информации. (Можно на английском, можно документацию) Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Personalized lock screen for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000197/personalized-lock-screen-for-android) нашел-таки. Теперь осталось разобраться.